# WPF: How to centre and scale a character on a Button?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

For a project I'm working on I want to create an on-screen keyboard. So I like to put a character on a button. But the problem with doing this is that I can't manage to get the character in full size and centered on the button. Somehow it seems to have some space above and under the character which i don't want in this case.

The code i use currently for a button is this:

```
<Button Grid.RowSpan="2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="40" Height="40" VerticalContentAlignment="Center">
        <Button.Background>
            <SolidColorBrush Color="Gray" Opacity="0.3" />
        </Button.Background>

        <Button.Content>
            <Viewbox>
                <TextBlock FontSize="40" FontFamily="Monotype Corsiva" Foreground="Red" Text="i" LineHeight="20px" LineStackingStrategy="BlockLineHeight" />
            </Viewbox>
        </Button.Content>
    </Button>
```

The result at the moment is this;

[Click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SQ6wS.png)

Does anybody know how to show the character in full size and centered on the button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will resize the text automatically with the button.

```
<Viewbox>
    <TextBlock Margin="-2,0,0,0"
               Padding="0"
               FontFamily="Monotype Corsiva"
               Foreground="Red"
               Text="i"
               LineStackingStrategy="BlockLineHeight" />
</Viewbox>
```

I think the character looks like it is off-centre because of the font you're using. I adjusted the position by setting the left value of the margin to a negative value (ie: `Margin="-2,0,0,0"`).

Comment: I'd hoped for a more simple solution (Like a Font independant solution), but this helps me out!

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you have to add a Canvas in addition to the Grid, in a Button and use negative margin to get it center however you want it to be.

```
<Button Width="30" Height="30">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Canvas Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0">
            <TextBlock Canvas.Bottom="-22" Canvas.Right="-10" FontSize="35">h</TextBlock>
        </Canvas>                
    </Grid>
</Button>
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your fast response, but it's still not perfect. It's now centered, but not filling the button! There's still a lot of space around the character

Comment: I do not quite understand, can't you just make the font bigger?

Comment: Nope, it wont make the font bigger, Try this for more clearity:

<Viewbox>
                <Grid ShowGridLines="True">
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition />
</Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Border BorderThickness="2" BorderBrush="LightBlue">
                    <TextBlock Background="Yellow" Foreground="Red">h</TextBlock>
                </Border>
                </Grid>
            </Viewbox>

Comment: Sorry for the bad layout, but please put this as content in a button

Comment: See edited answer. You can add a Canvas to position the text. It will work but I guess you would need to adjust each margin differently unless you adopt a font that has uniform width